# Generate backlog data from created and modified timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset that looks like

```
Invoice Id Created Date        Modified Date      
107736     2019-01-28 02:05:07 2019-01-28 02:10:34
107737     2019-01-28 02:10:09 2019-01-28 02:15:50
107738     2019-01-28 03:16:28 2019-01-28 03:20:41
107739     2019-01-28 03:16:28 2019-01-28 03:20:54
107740     2019-01-28 05:57:04 2019-01-28 06:00:52
107741     2019-01-28 06:02:07 2019-01-28 06:05:54
107742     2019-01-28 06:27:14 2019-01-28 06:31:21
107743     2019-01-28 06:27:15 2019-01-28 06:30:51
107744     2019-01-28 06:27:15 2019-01-28 06:32:07
107745     2019-01-28 06:27:15 2019-01-28 06:31:46
107746     2019-01-28 06:27:15 2019-01-28 06:31:06
107747     2019-01-28 06:32:19 2019-01-28 06:36:17
107748     2019-01-28 06:32:19 2019-01-28 06:36:02
107749     2019-01-28 06:32:19 2019-01-28 06:35:43
107750     2019-01-28 06:37:22 2019-01-28 06:41:58
107751     2019-01-28 06:37:24 2019-01-28 06:40:48
107752     2019-01-28 06:37:25 2019-01-28 06:41:40
107753     2019-01-28 06:37:25 2019-01-28 06:41:02
107754     2019-01-28 06:37:25 2019-01-28 06:42:21
107755     2019-01-28 06:42:29 2019-01-28 06:47:04
```

I want to generate a dataset that tells me the backlog at every 5 minute intervals.

Eg: At time 2019-01-28 02:05:00 backlog = 0 since no invoice exists

At 2019-01-28 02:10:00 backlog = 1 since 1st invoice has been created but not modified

At 2019-01-28 06:30:00 backlog = 5 since 1st invoice has been created but not modified

How do I generate this with pandas?

A better definition of backlog at time `t = ((df['Created Date'] < t) & (df['Modified Date'] > t)).sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that no invoice can be modified before it is created then you can just group by 5 mins `'Created Date'` and subtract the group by of `'Modified Date'` and then show the `cumsum()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Created Date', freq='5Min'))['Invoice Id'].count()
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Modified Date', freq='5Min'))['Invoice Id'].count()
df1.subtract(df2, fill_value=0).rename('Backlog').astype(int).cumsum()

Out[]:
2019-01-28 02:05:00    1
2019-01-28 02:10:00    1
2019-01-28 02:15:00    0
2019-01-28 02:20:00    0
2019-01-28 02:25:00    0
... snip ...
2019-01-28 06:25:00    5
2019-01-28 06:30:00    3
2019-01-28 06:35:00    5
2019-01-28 06:40:00    1
2019-01-28 06:45:00    0
Freq: 5T, Name: Backlog, dtype: int64
```

Note: This is 5 min off your example because it shows the beginning of the time interval, e.g. `02:05 - 02:10 = 1`. You can extend your index to include `02:00 - 02:05 = 0` if you want.